# Keyword suggestion Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, nlp, keyword

I have been working on a project which asks me to give keyword/keyphrase suggestion based on description of the product.

What I have currently: Description of the Product, Category of product(May or may not be present).

What I want: Machine generated keywords/keyphrases based on description.

What research I have done: (NLP Based approach) This problem can be broken down into two separate approaches.

- Not using the past Data : Just summarizing on current description
- Method: - Tokenization, stemming, stopwords removal etc. (Preprocessing)
- Shallow NLP (Constituency Parsing) and retain only NP & JJ phrases.

This would be an approach which doesn't use description present in database.

What I was looking for is a better approach which uses ML algorithms and also uses my past product description data.

I was thinking about applying shallow parsing on entire dataset, and then give keywords which encounters in more than N number of products.

What algorithm or approach would come in handy? 
How can I use my data?

Comment: Do you have a large set of products with keywords already in place that you can use for learning?

Comment: Yes, I do have keywords related to "some" of the product descriptions.

Answer (score 0):

Try to look at basic models Like: Term Frequency or TF-IDF, This give you some important words: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf,
Then search for **text clustering**(For cluster text into group that are related to each other) and **Topic detection approaches**(this can help you find prominent words and topic related to a document)

Then you can find keyword for each cluster(also you can consider categories of documents), and try to find most relevant words to another words

I suggest read some/or whole chapters of this book: http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf

Comment: Can I do document(Description) similarity(Which basically is based on TF-IDF)? And then suggest keywords which are found in most documents out of a list of similar documents?